# Deploying Laravel+Vue on shared hosting

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I have done an SPA using Laravel and the Vue coming with it. It's working fine locally. The problem came when I tried to deploy it to a shared hosting. The static part of the index file (blade file) is working, but vue components are not showing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use SSH to connect ?

Comment: Have check if there is any error in develop tools related to js. Because Laravel-mix compiles all js code to a single file which placed at public folder. So it does not matter whether you have installed npm or not on server.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect in the browser, your js files are not found mostly, provide the structure of the directory in the hosting server, check you have the node modules in your server or not,  and the errors showing in the inspection.

Run `npm install` and `composer update` in the server.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the cached views. It worked fine when I deleted all files in storage/framework/views